Campaign Monitor - Subscriber List for Journey Inconsistencies when Adding Subscribers
I'm implementing campaign monitor into a web app using the .NET SDK they have available. Currently, our flow is using a Journey that initiates an email when a subscriber is added to a segment in a list. It's also important to note that I selected the option to send every time the subscriber is added to the segment, not just the first. The subscriber is added to the segment if a custom field "ParticipantStatus" is equal to "Active". At the end of the flow after the email is sent, the custom field "ParticipantStatus" gets set back to "Inactive" to allow us to update the subscriber if we want to send another email.
Flow of Journey
using createsend_dotnet;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CMTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AuthenticationDetails auth = new ApiKeyAuthenticationDetails("<apiKey>");
            Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(auth, "<listId>");

            List<SubscriberDetail> subsToAdd = new();

            SubscriberDetail clientSub = new("<emailAddress>", "", new List<SubscriberCustomField>());

            clientSub.CustomFields.Add(new() { Key = "Subject", Value = "New Subject" });
            clientSub.CustomFields.Add(new() { Key = "Body", Value = "New Body" });
            clientSub.CustomFields.Add(new() { Key = "ParticipantStatus", Value = "Active" });

            clientSub.ConsentToTrack = ConsentToTrack.Unchanged;
            clientSub.ConsentToSendSms = ConsentToSendSms.Unchanged;

            subsToAdd.Add(clientSub);

            try
            {
                BulkImportResults results = subscriber.Import(subsToAdd, true, true, true);

                Console.WriteLine(results.TotalNewSubscribers + " new subscribers added. " + results.TotalExistingSubscribers + " existing subscribers updated.");
            }
            catch (CreatesendException ex)
            {
                ErrorResult<BulkImportResults> error = (ErrorResult<BulkImportResults>)ex.Data["ErrorResult"]!;

                Console.WriteLine($"Encountered Createsend Exception in EmailService > AddSubscriber. Response Code: {error.Code}. Message: {error.Message}.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encountered error in EmailService > AddSubscriber: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}





However, when we've tested this functionality, it seems inconsistent when the email will actually send. The first time that they're added to the segment it will send the email 100% of the time, but after that it seems to only work on occasion. I'm wondering if there's some limit on the times you can get emails to send in a certain window of time, but the API always returns a success code as we're making these requests.
UPDATE: I tested this without a segment-based trigger as a sanity check. I used a 'Subscriber joins the list' trigger and found out that when I add subscribers and delete them, it will only send an email consistently if I wait 30 minutes between each time I add and delete. If anybody knows how to eliminate the 30-minute buffer period between when emails are allowed to be sent, please let me know.
